# React state update (SWR) and component refresh?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, swr

I'm using [SWR to fetch data as stated in the docs](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/pagination#when-to-use-useswr):

```
function App () {
  const [pageIndex, setPageIndex] = useState(0);

  // The API URL includes the page index, which is a React state.
  const { data } = useSWR(`/api/data?page=${pageIndex}`, fetcher);

  // ... handle loading and error states

  return <div>
    {data.map(item => <div key={item.id}>{item.name}</div>)}
    <button onClick={() => setPageIndex(pageIndex - 1)}>Previous</button>
    <button onClick={() => setPageIndex(pageIndex + 1)}>Next</button>
  </div>
}
```

The only difference in my case is I'm loading more items on the same page (so more like infinite scroll not pagination), but here's the trouble:

```
const { data } = useSWR(`/api/data?page=${pageIndex}`, fetcher);
```

Notice how data is fetched based on `pageIndex` variable, that comes from the state. Once it changes everything rerenders, so instead of getting more items every time user clicks on a button I'm always getting a refresh, then user sees initial render, then new items. So in short I want to load more items at the bottom of the page, not refresh everything and then add the items... What am I missing? There's useSWRInfinite, but it's the same story, it gets url data from the state...

Comment: Maybe collect the paginated `data` into state and render the entire data state and not just the current data page. You might not need both a prev ***and*** next button since presumably you've fetched, and stored, all previous page's data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would cache all the previously fetched pages in local state. Use a `useEffect` hook with a dependency on `pageIndex` state and current `data` value, store the data in an object using the current `pageIndex` as the key. When rendering all the fetched pages flatten the array of `pages` values to a single renderable array.

```
function App () {
  const [pageIndex, setPageIndex] = useState(0);
  const [pages, setPages] = useState({});

  // The API URL includes the page index, which is a React state.
  const { data } = useSWR(`/api/data?page=${pageIndex}`, fetcher);

  useEffect(() => {
    // cache page in state
    setPages(pages => ({
      [pageIndex]: data,
    }));
  }, [data, pageIndex]);

  // ... handle loading and error states

  // NOTE: pages is an object of arrays, so flatten values to single array to render

  return <div>
    {Object.values(pages).flatten().map(item => (
      <div key={item.id}>{item.name}</div>
    ))}
    <button onClick={() => setPageIndex(page => page - 1)}>Previous</button>
    <button onClick={() => setPageIndex(page => page + 1)}>Next</button>
  </div>
}
```